# Why are empty strings returned in split() results?

Tags: python, string, split

What is the point of `'/segment/segment/'.split('/')` returning `['', 'segment', 'segment', '']`?

Notice the empty elements. If you're splitting on a delimiter that happens to be at position one and at the very end of a string, what extra value does it give you to have the empty string returned from each end?

Comment: I have the same question and searched it for a long time. Now I understand the empty results are really important. Thanks for your question.

Comment: A solution is to use `strip()` to strip leading and trailing split characters from the string before splitting: `'/segment/segment/'.strip('/').split('/')`

Comment: That solution doesn't work for the case `'/segment//segment/'.split('/')`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) complements [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), so

```
"/".join(['', 'segment', 'segment', ''])
```

gets you back the original string.

If the empty strings were not there, the first and last `'/'` would be missing after the `join()`.

Answer (score 150):

More generally, to remove empty strings returned in `split()` results, you may want to look at the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.

Example:

```
f = filter(None, '/segment/segment/'.split('/'))
s_all = list(f)
```

returns

```
['segment', 'segment']
```

Comment: If you prefer list comprehensions: `[x for x in '/segment/segment/'.split('/') if x]`

Answer (score 37):

There are two main points to consider here:

- Expecting the result of `'/segment/segment/'.split('/')` to be equal to `['segment', 'segment']` is reasonable, but then this loses information.  If `split()` worked the way you wanted, if I tell you that `a.split('/') == ['segment', 'segment']`, you can't tell me what `a` was.
- What should be the result of `'a//b'.split()` be? `['a', 'b']`?, or `['a', '', 'b']`? I.e., should `split()` merge adjacent delimiters?  If it should, then it will be very hard to parse data that's delimited by a character, and some of the fields can be empty.  I am fairly sure there are many people who *do* want the empty values in the result for the above case!

In the end, it boils down to two things:

Consistency: if I have `n` delimiters, in `a`, I get `n+1` values back after the `split()`.

It should be possible to do complex things, and easy to do simple things: if you want to ignore empty strings as a result of the `split()`, you can always do:

```
def mysplit(s, delim=None):
    return [x for x in s.split(delim) if x]
```

but if one doesn't want to ignore the empty values, one *should* be able to.

The language has to pick one definition of `split()`—there are too many different use cases to satisfy everyone's requirement as a default.  I think that Python's choice is a good one, and is the most logical.  (As an aside, one of the reasons I don't like C's `strtok()` is because it merges adjacent delimiters, making it extremely hard to do serious parsing/tokenization with it.)

There is one exception: `a.split()` without an argument squeezes consecutive white-space, but one can argue that this is the right thing to do in that case.  If you don't want the behavior, you can always to `a.split(' ')`.

Comment: For those wondering whether it's faster to nuke duplicate spaces, then split, or to split and only take non-empty strings, here's what I get:
`python3 -m timeit "import re ; re.sub(' +', '  foo  bar   baz   ', '').split(' ')"` -> 875 nsec per loop; `python3 -m timeit "[token for token in '  foo  bar   baz   '.split(' ') if token]"` -> 616 nsec per loop

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for?  You get three matches because you have three delimiters.  If you don't want that empty one, just use:

```
'/segment/segment/'.strip('/').split('/')
```

Comment: -1 because you get four matches not three, and also this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: +1 to counteract the neg.. He didn't say you would get three results back. He said "three matches" for "three delimiters", which sounds logical to me. You do not, however, get "four matches" of anything. You do get "four elements" returned in your result, though. Also, it does not directly answer the "why", but it does provide a simple way to get what he really wants... which I don't think deserves a downvote. If you're going to nitpick someone (with a downvote, no less) please be more careful! Cheers! 8^)

Comment: @wasatchwizard Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate the correction and the recommendation. Unfortunately, now my vote is locked and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 9):

Having `x.split(y)` always return a list of `1 + x.count(y)` items is a precious regularity -- as @gnibbler's already pointed out it makes `split` and `join` exact inverses of each other (as they obviously should be), it also precisely maps the semantics of all kinds of delimiter-joined records (such as `csv` file lines [[net of quoting issues]], lines from `/etc/group` in Unix, and so on), it allows (as @Roman's answer mentioned) easy checks for (e.g.) absolute vs relative paths (in file paths and URLs), and so forth.

Another way to look at it is that you shouldn't wantonly toss information out of the window for no gain.  What would be gained in making `x.split(y)` equivalent to `x.strip(y).split(y)`?  Nothing, of course -- it's easy to use the second form when that's what you mean, but if the first form was arbitrarily deemed to mean the second one, you'd have lot of work to do when you **do** want the first one (which is far from rare, as the previous paragraph points out).

But really, thinking in terms of mathematical regularity is the simplest and most general way you can teach yourself to design passable APIs.  To take a different example, it's very important that for any valid `x` and `y` `x == x[:y] + x[y:]` -- which immediately indicates why one extreme of a slicing *should* be excluded.  The simpler the invariant assertion you can formulate, the likelier it is that the resulting semantics are what you need in real life uses -- part of the mystical fact that maths is very useful in dealing with the universe.

Try formulating the invariant for a `split` dialect in which leading and trailing delimiters are special-cased... counter-example: string methods such as `isspace` are not maximally simple -- `x.isspace()` is equivalent to `x and all(c in string.whitespace for c in x)` -- that silly leading `x and` is why you so often find yourself coding `not x or x.isspace()`, to get back to the simplicity which *should* have been designed into the `is...` string methods (whereby an empty string "is" anything you want -- contrary to man-in-the-street horse-sense, maybe [[empty sets, like zero &c, have always confused most people;-)]], but fully conforming to obvious well-refined *mathematical* common-sense!-).

Answer (score 6):

Well, it lets you know there was a delimiter there. So, seeing 4 results lets you know you had 3 delimiters. This gives you the power to do whatever you want with this information, rather than having Python drop the empty elements, and then making you manually check for starting or ending delimiters if you need to know it.

Simple example: Say you want to check for absolute vs. relative filenames. This way you can do it all with the split, without also having to check what the first character of your filename is.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this minimal example:

```
>>> '/'.split('/')
['', '']
```

`split` must give you what's before and after the delimiter `'/'`, but there are no other characters. So it *has* to give you the empty string, which technically precedes and follows the `'/'`, because `'' + '/' + '' == '/'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want empty spaces to be returned by `split` use it without args.

```py
>>> "  this   is  a sentence ".split()
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

```py
>>> "  this   is  a sentence ".split(" ")
['', '', 'this', '', '', 'is', '', 'a', 'sentence', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

always use strip function before split if want to ignore blank lines.

youroutput.strip().split('splitter')

Example:

```
     yourstring =' \nhey\njohn\nhow\n\nare\nyou'
   
    yourstring.strip().split('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to come up with new ways to do this.
Here is a code that removes all the whitespaces and some results. I am interested if it can be made to remove them only at the beginning and the end of the given string.

```
import string
print(list(string.whitespace))
print({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace})
s = '  Hi Stackoverflow \n\t Mi\t\n\r\x0bhai\r\t  Here '
print(s.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace}))
```

Results:

```
[' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', '\x0b', '\x0c']
{32: None, 9: None, 10: None, 13: None, 11: None, 12: None}
HiStackoverflowMihaiHere
```