# In Python, what is a minimal way of assigning a value to a variable depending on whether a dictionary contains a key?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I want to access a few values in a dictionary in a way something like the following:

```
self.userName              = self.options["--username"]
self.files                 = self.options["--files"].split(",")
self.configurationFileName = self.options["--configuration"]
```

However, it may be that some of these keys may not exist in the dictionary -- let's say "--files" might not be in it. If the key does not exist in the dictionary, I want the value of the variable to be set to `None`, i.e. `self.files = None`. At present, I am doing something like the following:

```
if "--files" in self.options:
    self.files = self.options["--files"].split(",")
else:
    self.files = None
```

Would there be some way of doing this that would be a bit more minimal, efficient or Pythonic? I would prefer this to be done in a one-liner for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `get` and an empty string as default and substitute with `None` in case of empty string or empty list:

```
self.files = self.options.get('--files', "").split(",") or None
```

This way `split` is always called on a valid object, and you get `None` if the object is empty.

EDIT

Actually the tests I made used `split()` which [uses a different algorithm than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645083/when-splitting-an-empty-string-in-python-why-does-split-return-an-empty-list) `split(",")`

So to work, it should be

```
self.files = self.options.get('--files', "").replace(',', '\n').split() or None
```

Another way to do it using `set` operations:

```
self.files = set(self.options.get('--files', "").split(",")) ^ set(['']) or None
```

but then `self.files` is a set and not a list.

AFTERTHOUGHT:

what I would do is define a small helper class

```
class NoneFound:
  @classmethod
  def split(self, _):
    return None
```

and then simply:

```
self.files = self.options.get('--files', NoneFound).split(',')
```

See with that class defined:

```
>>> print {'--files': "a,b,c"}.get("--files", NoneFound).split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print {}.get("--files", NoneFound).split(',')
None
```

Comment: I find this very unpythonic. Using a line or two less in exchange for being harder to read and understand.

Comment: Oh, that is sensible, very readable and a one-liner. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: this doesn't work, splitting a empty string returns a list with a empty string which is true: see http://ideone.com/w7ur6x

Answer (score 3):

use [get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
self.files = self.options.get('--files', None)
if self.files:
    self.files.split(',')
```

Comment: This method still requires type checking, as `None` doesn't have a `split` method. So you're just moving around when/what you need to check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that. The use of the method ```get``` was of particular use. You can see in [the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877977/1556092) provided by [damienfrancois](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1763614/damienfrancois) that the type checking can be brought cleanly into one line with the ```get```.

Answer (score 3):

The Pythonic way to get a dictionary key with default value if the key isn't present is `get`, e.g.

```
self.user_name = self.options.get("--username", None)
self.configuration_file_name = self.options.get("--configuration", None)
```

As for the files option, you could use the same approach and do the split afterwards:

```
self.files = self.options.get("--files", None)
if self.files:
    self.files = self.files.split(",")
```

or use a try/except block:

```
try:
    self.files = self.options["--files"].split(",")
except KeyError:
    self.files = None
```

or, if you really want it on one line, use a conditional expression:

```
self.files = self.options["--files"].split(",") if "--files" in self.options else None
```

I'm guessing opinions on which way to handle "--files" is most Pythonic will differ. I would go with the first case above (use `get` and check do the split afterwards) because it's consistent with using `get` which is definitely the Pythonic way to handle the general case of a not-found dictionary value, and I find this way of handling the split logic most obvious and easy to understand.

Note that since you ask about being Pythonic, I used underscore_case instead of camelCase. That's the Python way for variable naming.

Comment: As I responded to @HasanRamezani, this method still requires type checking, as None doesn't have a split method. So you're just moving around when/what you need to check.

Comment: @RogerFan - true, but that's really just for the case of the files. For the general case (and 2 out of the 3 examples in the question), `get` is clearly the Pythonic way to do it, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: For the files case I slightly prefer to try-except block, but that's probably because that's how I learned it. Not a lot of difference. I hate the single-line if-else clause though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that. The use of the get method of was of particular use.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Pythonic way is to use a try-except block, especially when you expect the operation to succeed most of the time. See [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

```
try:
    self.files = self.options["--files"].split(",")
except KeyError:
    self.files = None
```

If you expect it to succeed most of the time, you can check first as you have done (see [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl)). In general, this isn't really a big deal, use whatever method makes more sense in your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that. Your references to documentation on what is Pythonic were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a step back and ask "Why am I storing a comma-delimited string in `self.options['--files']` instead of a list in the first place?". If you did that, then your code would simply be

```
self.files = self.options.get("--files")
```

Whatever populates `self.options` should split the list first.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on that. The reason why the string is stored rather than a list (which would, indeed, be nicer) is because it is input from command line options. I'm using [docopt](http://docopt.org/) to convert the command line options to a dictionary.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way in `docopt` to process the argument. You could use `[--file=<arg>]...`, but I understand that `--file f1 --file f2 --file f3` would be far less desirable than `--files f1,f2,f3`. In `argparse`, for instance, you could define the option as `p.add_argument('--files', type=lambda x: x.split(','))` to automatically convert the comma-separated string to a list.