# How can split string in python and get result with delimiter?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have code like

```
a = "*abc*bbc"
a.split("*")#['','abc','bbc']
#i need ["*","abc","*","bbc"] 
a = "abc*bbc"
a.split("*")#['abc','bbc']
#i need ["abc","*","bbc"]
```

How can i get list with delimiter in python **split** function or **regex** or **partition** ?
I am using python 2.7 , windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use RegEx with the delimiter as a group and ignore the empty string, like this

```
>>> [item for item in re.split(r"(\*)", "abc*bbc") if item]
['abc', '*', 'bbc']
>>> [item for item in re.split(r"(\*)", "*abc*bbc") if item]
['*', 'abc', '*', 'bbc']
```

**Note 1:** You need to escape `*` with `\`, because RegEx has special meaning for `*`. So, you need to tell RegEx engine that `*` should be treated as the normal character.

**Note 2:** You ll be getting an empty string, when you are splitting the string where the delimiter is at the beginning or at the end. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16645083/1903116) to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: `filter(None, re.split('([*])', '*abc*bbc'))`

Comment: @hwnd Actually, List Comprehension is preferred over the `filter` in Python :)

Comment: Yes, preferred but still not bad =)

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
x="*abc*bbc"
print [x for x in re.split(r"(\*)",x) if x]
```

You have to use `re.split` and group the delimiter.

or

```
x="*abc*bbc"
print re.findall(r"[^*]+|\*",x)
```

Or thru `re.findall`

Answer (score 2):

Use `partition()`;

```
a = "abc*bbc"
print (a.partition("*"))

>>> 
('abc', '*', 'bbc')
>>>
```