# python split empty string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Could someone explain this behaviour on python 2.7.8:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 12 2014, 02:03:09)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ''
>>> a.split()
[]
>>> a.split('\n')
['']
```

split by any white space gives an empty list, but split by new line gives a list with an empty string. WHY?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [python wiki](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :

> **str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])**
>
> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`). The sep argument may consist of multiple characters (for example, `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2', '3']`). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns `['']`.
>
> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

For more explanation read this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645307/2867928

Comment: ok, I see. I still find this confusing though... Thanks.

Comment: @WeaselFox pleas read the second part its very clear! i'll add more explain in answer!

Answer (score 5):

From python str.split docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
>   are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',')
>   returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may consist of multiple
>   characters (for example, '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') returns ['1', '2',
>   '3']). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator **returns
>   ['']**.
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator **returns []**.

Comment: You should also mention that the latter splitting algorithm splits on all white space, not just spaces. Which isn't immediately obvious from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Providing *any* character will create a list:

```
>>> a = ''
>>> a.split()
[]
>>> a.split(' ')
['']
```

Regardless of the character. It behaves this way because it looks for a character, splits the string into a list, and gives list items for the left and right of the character.

```
>>> a = 'This is a test.'
>>> a.split('a')
['This is ', ' test.']
```

If there is no matching character, there is nothing on either side of the character.

```
>>> a = 'Another test string.'
>>> a.split('*')
['Another test string.']
```

Comment: ok... but why? I find this weird..

Comment: Because the `split` method looks for the character, and splits the string at that point. Since it can't find it, it returns an empty string. @WeaselFox

Comment: Please check my update; it should provide an explanation and example for the behavior of `split`. @WeaselFox

Answer (score -2):

When you tell python to split('\n') it is separating different lines. Therefore returning the first line it finds which is... '' . If your input had more than one line for example: 
a = line1\nline2

it would print out those lines.

Edit: added \n between line1 and line2, an enter = to a \n