# Python regex library re is counts a word when string is empty

Tags: python, regex, split, string, word-count

The situation is as following:

With the following piece of code:

```
import re

content = ''
count = len(re.split('\W+', content, flags=re.UNICODE))

print(count)

# Output is expected to be 0, as it has no words
# Instead output is 1
```

What is going wrong? All other word counts are correct.

***EDIT:*** It also happens when we use a string `content = '..'` or `content = '.!'` thus this in ***NOT*** a problem related in any sense with python's `split()` function but with the regular expressions from `re`.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** Although the solution I gave works in my particular case the correct solution is not yet met. Because it's an regex issue which isn't yet ***100% SOLVED***!

Comment: Not a duplicate because re an independent library and is expected to return only word and filter the occurrence mentioned in the other post.

Comment: how it returns only word characters where the input string is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970724/python-split-empty-string

Comment: No @AvinashRaj, it returns an array with an empty string when the input is an empty string in the link you mentioned this works correctly in the split function and doesn't when the string is `"\n"`. This is something that has to do with the `re.split()` function.

Comment: It has to do with this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

Comment: It also happens when the string `'..'` is used...

Comment: What happens with this `..` input? It spits according to one or more non-word characters and finally returns you two empty strings. It works correctly.

Comment: No @AvinashRaj, It does not work correctly in the scope of the problem. I want to count the existing words. Not "empty" words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found out what the reason is:

When `re.split()` is used, it splits a string based on the regular expression given and returns an array of strings. If string is empty and thus there is nothing to split, it apparantly return an array with an empty string in it (`['']`). So when the `len()` function is used it counts an array with 1 element.

A solution to this is the following piece of code:

```
import re

content = ''
count = [len(re.split('\W+', content, flags=re.UNICODE)), 0][content == '']

print(count)

# Output is as expected, 0, by using a simple if statement
# that verifies if string is empty, when it's empty it return 0,
# otherwise, it returns the word count.
```