# IndexError: list index out of range - Python/Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

In my recent project, I trying to send serially data from Arduino to Python. Using pyserial it is done perfectly. But I have one problem here. I can't able to split my data. All are stored in one variable in Python coed but I want to split it.

Aduino Code:

```
#define sw1 6
#define sw2 5
#define sw3 4
#define sw4 3

int vote1 = 0;
int vote2 = 0;
int vote3 = 0;
int vote4 = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(sw1, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw2, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw3, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw4, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(sw1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sw2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sw3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(sw4, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(sw1) == 0)
  {
    vote1++;
    Serial.print(vote1);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote2);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote3);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote4);

    while (digitalRead(sw1) == 0);
  }
  if (digitalRead(sw2) == 0)
  {
    vote2++;
    Serial.print(vote1);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote2);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote3);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote4);

    while (digitalRead(sw2) == 0);
  }
  if (digitalRead(sw3) == 0)
  {
    vote3++;
    Serial.print(vote1);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote2);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote3);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote4);

    while (digitalRead(sw3) == 0);
  }
  if (digitalRead(sw4) == 0)
  {
    vote4++;
    Serial.print(vote1);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote2);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote3);
    Serial.print(("\t"));
    Serial.print(vote4);

    while (digitalRead(sw4) == 0);
  }
}
```

Here, I'm trying to send four different value from Arduino to Python using four button.

Python Code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)

while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    data = arduinoData.split("\t")

    a = data[0]
    b = data[1]
    c = data[2]
    d = data[3]
```

And I got error like below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/serialConnection_2.py", line 11, in 
>       b = data[1] IndexError: list index out of range

If I change my python code like below:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)

while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    data = arduinoData.split("\t")

    print(data)
```

Then I can able to receive all four value in form of list like below:

```
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['']
['1 , 0 , 0 , 0']
['2 , 0 , 0 , 0']
['3 , 0 , 0 , 0']
['4 , 0 , 0 , 0']
['4 , 1 , 0 , 0']
['4 , 1 , 1 , 0']
['4 , 1 , 2 , 0']
['4 , 1 , 2 , 1']
['4 , 1 , 2 , 2']
['4 , 1 , 2 , 3']
['']
['']
['']
```

When ever I press button according that list's value is update properly. I don't know why I can't able to access list's members.

Comment: Apparently you also get a lot of empty lines. You could discard them: `if not arduinoData:` `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

`split` in Python returns `['']` when the input [string is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16645083/260411). Then you're trying to access an index inside `data` that doesn't exist (i.e. `data[1]`, etc.) because your serial is receiving many empty strings, thus try checking for presence before treating the data:

```
arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
if arduinoData:
    data = arduinoData.split("\t")

    a = data[0]
    b = data[1]
    c = data[2]
    d = data[3]
```