# python split without creating blanks

Tags: python, string, split

I understand why it is important to create blanks using split thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results), but sometimes it is necessary not to grab them.

lets say you parsed some css and got the following strings:

```
s1 = 'background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'
s2 = 'color:#000;background-color:#fff;border:1px #333 dotted'
```

both are valid css even though there is a semicolon lacking at the end of the string. when splitting the strings, you get the following:

```
>>> s1.split(';')
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted', '']
>>> s2.split(';')
['color:#000', 'background-color:#fff', 'border:1px #333 dotted']
```

that extra semicolon creates a blank item in the list. now if I want to manipulate further I would need to test the beginning and end of each list, and remove them if they are blank, which is not that bad, but seems avoidable.

## question:

is there a method that is essentially the same as `split` but does not include trailing blank items? or is there simply a way to remove those just like a string has `strip` to remove the trailing whitespace

Answer (score 14):

Simply remove the items with the `None` filter:

```
filter(None, s1.split(';'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> s1 = 'background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'
>>> filter(None, s1.split(';'))
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted']
```

Calling `filter()` with `None` removes all 'empty' or numeric 0 items; anything that would evaluate to false in a boolean context.

`filter(None, ....)` eats list comprehensions for breakfast:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('filter(None, a)', "a = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, 'five', ''] * 100")
9.410392045974731
>>> timeit.timeit('[i for i in a if i]', "a = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, 'five', ''] * 100")
44.9318630695343
```

Comment: Isn't filter slower than a list comprehension? (I'm not saying that my answer is better than yours, I'm just wondering)

Comment: although all answers work, this answer is the one that actually answers my question and does not simply make it work for my situation. Thanks. I am going to bed now, but I will accept the answer in the morning

Comment: @Haidro: `filter()` with `None` is *one* C operation, no Python looping done. I'd say it is faster. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about performance, but GvR was thinking about getting rid of it, along with other lispy built-ins like `map` and `reduce`. In Python 3 `reduce` was moved to the `functools` module. I like the lispies but it is not idiomatic Python.

Comment: @PauloScardine Someone linked this to me the other day about it: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @PauloScardine: Yes, Guido had an aversion of functional programming constructs until others convinced him of their use. `reduce` was the only victim in the end, and it was moved to `functools` rather than be removed altogether.

Comment: @Haidro: I tested `filter(None, ...)` versus a list comp and the filter was 5 times as fast.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out the empty strings, as an empty string is considered `False`:

```
>>> s1 = 'background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'
>>> [i for i in s1.split(';') if i]
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted']
```

Alternatively, you can [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) the semicolon first:

```
>>> s1.rstrip(';').split(';')
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted']
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply `str.strip` to the string before doing the `split`:

```
>>> s1 = 'background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'
...     
>>> s1.strip(';').split(';')
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted']
```

Works for both leading and trailing `';'`:

```
>>> s1 = ';background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'
>>> s1.strip(';').split(';')
['background-color:#000', 'color:#fff', 'border:1px #ccc dotted']
```

I am not sure why you would want to avoid this as a strip before split is going to be faster than both `LC`  and `filter`:

```
>>> s1 = ';background-color:#000;color:#fff;border:1px #ccc dotted;'*1000
>>> %timeit filter(None, s1.split(';'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 638 us per loop
>>> %timeit s1.strip(';').split(';')
1000 loops, best of 3: 570 us per loop
>>> %timeit [i for i in s1.split(';') if i]
100 loops, best of 3: 931 us per loop
```