# how can i split string with no blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
input = '1+2++3+++4++5+6+7++8+9++10'
string = input.split('+')
print(string)
```

when we run this code the output is `['1', '2', '', '3', '', '', '4', '', '5', '6', '7', '', '8', '9', '',  '10']`

But i want to split the string with no blank like `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']`

Is there any function or method to remove blanks without using for loop like

```
for i in string:
if i == '':
    string.remove(i)
```

Comment: Very related: [python - Why are empty strings returned in split() results? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results) , [string - python split without creating blanks - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542152/python-split-without-creating-blanks)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split by 1 or more occurrences of a delimiter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492415/how-can-i-split-by-1-or-more-occurrences-of-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a `list` based on the output of split, and only include the elements which are not `None`

You can achieve this in multiple ways. The cleanest way here would be to use `regex`.

Regex:

```
import re
re.split('\++', inp)
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

List Comprehension:

```
inp = '1+2++3+++4++5+6+7++8+9++10'
[s for s in inp.split('+') if s]
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Loop & Append:

```
result = []
for s in inp.split('+'):
    if s:
        result.append(s)

result
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

```
customStr="1+2++3+++4++5+6+7++8+9++10"

list( filter( lambda x : x!="" ,customStr.split("+") ) )
```