# Why does len("".split(" ")) give 1? python

Tags: python, string

What is the pythonic explanation for `len("".split(" ")) == 1` showing True?

Why does the `"".split("")` yield `['']`

```
>>> len("".split(" "))
1
>>> "".split(" ")
['']
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`str.split(sep)` returns *at least* one element. If *sep* was not found in the text, that one element is the original, unsplit text.

For an empty string, the *sep* delimiter will of course never be found, and is specifically called out in the documentation:

> Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns `['']`.

You probably are confused by the behaviour of the `None` delimiter option (the default):

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. **Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.**

(emphasis mine). That makes `str.split(None)` the *exception*, not the rule.

Comment: Nice explanation and the quirk of the varieties!

Answer (score 4):

[] has length zero. If a list contains anything in it, anything at all, it will have a 
length >=1 . In this case, ['']  has one element in it: the empty string. So it gives one.

Answer (score 2):

this might be relevant:

[Why are empty strings returned in split() results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results)

split() is designed to be opposite of join() and:

```
" ".join([""]) == ""
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, since it is also true for an empty list, `" ".join([]) == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you the length of the list that is produced, not the length of the string.