# python 2.7.8 delimiter.how to del a a letter of string

Tags: python-2.7, delimiter

```
def split(string,x):
    if string == "":
        return ""
    if string[0] == x :
        return split(string[1:],x)
    return string[0]+[split(string[1:],x)]
```

I want to give this func a string like "ballooolam" and "l" and I want this func to give me ["ba","ooo","am"] 3 days I'm thinking about it

Comment: Why not using string.split('l')????? Or is this an exercise

Comment: almost it is though thinking to solve the problem in that way is good

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you meanby that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to split on a character in python is to use the `split` builtin. It will be *much* faster than anything you implement natively in python as it is a compiled C extension, as are all builtins at this point:

```
lst =  "ballooolam".split("l")
```

However, as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results), this might not *quite* do what you expect. `split` leaves empty strings in the list when there are tokens of zero length; I.E. if the delimeter is at the first/last position in the string, or if two delimeters are next to each other. This is so that doing `word = 'l'.join(lst)` will return the original value; Without the empty strings, you would get `'balooolam'` back instead of `'ballooolam'`. If you want to remove these empty strings, you can do it easily with a list-comprehension:

```
def splitter(string, x):
    return [token for token in string.split(x) if token]
```

The `if token` will reject any string that is 'falsy', which empty strings are. If you'd also like to exclude whitespace-only strings from the final list, you can do that with a little tweak:

```
def splitter(string, x):
    return [token for token in string.split(x) if token.strip()]
```

`strip()` removes any leading/trailing whitespace from a string. In the case of a whitespace-only string, this will result in an empty string, which will then be falsy.