# Why are there extra empty strings at the beginning and end of the list returned by re.split?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to take a string of ints and/or floats and create a list of floats. The string is going to have these brackets in them that need to be ignored. I'm using `re.split`, but if my string begins and ends with a bracket, I get extra empty strings. Why is that?

Code:

```
import re
x = "[1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5]"
y =  "1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5"
p = re.compile(r'[^\d\.]+')
print p.split(x)
print p.split(y)
```

Output:

```
['', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5', '']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: None of the answers here actually **answer** the OP's question (i.e. "Why is that?"). Some answers can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results) stackoverflow question.

Comment: @SpaceMonkey55 you should place this as answer!

Answer (score 9):

If you use `re.split`, then a delimiter at the beginning or end of the string causes an empty string at the beginning or end of the array in the result.

If you don't want this, use `re.findall` with a regex that matches every sequence NOT containing delimiters.

Example:

```
import re

a = '[1 2 3 4]'
print(re.split(r'[^\d]+', a))
print(re.findall(r'[\d]+', a))
```

Output:

```
['', '1', '2', '3', '4', '']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

*As others have pointed out in their answers, this may not be the perfect solution for this problem, but it is a general answer to the problem described in the title of the question, which I also had to solve when I found this question using Google.*

Answer (score 1):

As a more pythonic way you can just use a list comprehension and `str.isdigit()` method to check of your character is digit :

```
>>> [i for i in y if i.isdigit()]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

And about your code first of all you need to split based on space or brackets that could be done with `[\[\] ]` and for get rid of empty strings that is for leading and trailing brackets you can first `strip` your string :

```
>>> y =  "1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5"
>>> re.split(r'[\[\] ]+',y)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> y =  "[1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5]"
>>> re.split(r'[\[\] ]+',y)
['', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5', '']
>>> re.split(r'[\[\] ]+',y.strip('[]'))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

You can also wrap your result with `filter` function and using `bool` function.

```
>>> filter(bool,re.split(r'[\[\] ]+',y))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `filter` to avoid empty results:

```
x = "[1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5]"

print filter(None, re.split(r'[^\d.]+', x))
# => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to capture the content you want instead of splitting the string. You can use this regex:

```
(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX6kW4/1)**

[image]

Python code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\d+)')
test_str = u"[1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5]"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```