# Trailing empty string after re.split()

Tags: python, python-re

I have two strings where I want to isolate sequences of digits from everything else.

For example:

```
import re
s = 'abc123abc'
print(re.split('(\d+)', s))
s = 'abc123abc123'
print(re.split('(\d+)', s))
```

The output looks like this:

['abc', '123', 'abc']
['abc', '123', 'abc', '123', '']

Note that in the second case, there's a trailing empty string.

Obviously I can test for that and remove it if necessary but it seems cumbersome and I wondered if the RE can be improved to account for this scenario.

Comment: Do you actually want `['123', '123']` as a result?

Comment: In this case, you can use `s.strip("1234567890")`, but what are you going to do for a more complicated regular expression?

Comment: In any case, IMO this is a duplicate of [Python - re.split: extra empty strings that the beginning and end list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924509/python-re-split-extra-empty-strings-that-the-beginning-and-end-list) Unless OP actually wants `['123', '123']` as a result, in which case the solution would be to use `findall`, not `split`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I should have been clearer in my question. Sorry. I want the output as shown but without the trailing empty string. Use of *filter* does what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and don't return this empty string like below:

```
>>> s = 'abc123abc123'
>>> re.split('(\d+)', s)
['abc', '123', 'abc', '123', '']

>>> list(filter(None,re.split('(\d+)', s)))
['abc', '123', 'abc', '123']
```

By thanks @chepner you can generate list comprehension like below:

```
>>> [x for x in re.split('(\d+)', s) if x]
['abc', '123', 'abc', '123']
```

If maybe you have symbols or other you need `split`:

```
>>> s = '&^%123abc123$#@123'
>>> list(filter(None,re.split('(\d+)', s)))
['&^%', '123', 'abc', '123', '$#@', '123']
```

Comment: You can also use a list comprehension or generator expression, with `x for x in re.split(...) if x`.

Comment: Just not elegant to overgenerate and then filter. Especially when the OP states that they can easily do that but don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use regular expressions for this would be [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
def bits(s):
    return re.findall(r"(\D+|\d+)", s)

bits("abc123abc123")
# ['abc', '123', 'abc', '123']
```

But it seems easier and more natural with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). After all, you are chunking an iterable based on a single condition:

```
from itertools import groupby

def bits(s):
    return ["".join(g) for _, g in groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)]

bits("abc123abc123")
# ['abc', '123', 'abc', '123']
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the implementation of `re.split()` itself: you can't change it. When the function splits, it doesn't check anything that comes after the capture group, so it can't choose for you to either keep or discard the empty string that is left after splitting. It just splits there and leaves the rest of the string (which can be empty) to the next cycle.

If you don't want that empty string, you can get rid of it in various ways before collecting the results into a list. user1740577's is one example, but personally I prefer a list comprehension, since it's more idiomatic for simple filter/map operations:

```py
parts = [part for part in re.split('(\d+)', s) if part]
```

I recommend against checking and getting rid of the element *after* the list has already been created, because it involves more operations and allocations.