# Creating a list given an equation with no spaces

Tags: python, string, list

I want to create a list given a string such as `'b123+xyz=1+z1$'` so that the list equals `['b123', '+', 'xyz', '=', '1', '+', 'z1', '$']`

Without spaces or a single repeating pattern, I do not know how to split the string into a list.

I tried creating if statements in a for loop to append the string when it reaches a character that is not a digit or letter through `isdigit` and `isalpha` but could not differentiate between variables and digits.

Comment: What is the criterion you want to split the string by? Is it simply alphanumerucal values interleaved with operators?

Comment: If this is an equation, why do you want `b123+xyz=1+z1$` to be `['b123', '+', 'xyz', '=', '1', '+', 'z1', '$']` ? Why not `['b123', '+', 'xyz', '=', '1', '+', 'z1$']`? Then split on operators.

Comment: is `**` potentially a valid operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to split your string. This works by using positive lookaheads and look behinds for none word chars.

```py
import re

sample = "b123+xyz=1+z1$"
split_sample = re.split("(?=\W)|(?:(?<=\W)(?!$))", sample)
print(split_sample)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['b123', '+', 'xyz', '=', '1', '+', 'z1', '$']
```

**REGEX EXPLAIN**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another regex approach giving the same result is:

```
split_sample = re.split(r"(\+|=|\$)", sample)[:-1]
```

The [:-1] is to remove the final empty string.

Comment: Upv but wonder if you’d not be better off with `li = [v for in <your split> if v]`.  That would fix trailing *and* leading empties and avoid unempty deletions.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Given the equation b123+xyz=1+z1$, break it down
into a list of variables and operators
"""
operators = ['+', '-', '/', '*', '=']

equation = 'b123+xyz=1+z1$'
equation_by_variable_and_operator = []
text = ''
for character in equation:
    if character not in operators:
        text = text + character
    elif character in operators and len(text):
        equation_by_variable_and_operator.append(text)
        equation_by_variable_and_operator.append(character)
        text = ''
# For the final variable
equation_by_variable_and_operator.append(text)
print(equation_by_variable_and_operator)
```

Output

```
['b123', '+', 'xyz', '=', '1', '+', 'z1$']
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward `regex` solution is;

```
equation = "b123+xyz=1+z1$"
equation_list = re.findall(r'\W+|\w+', equation)
print(equation_list)
```

This would also work with strings such as `-b**10`.

Using `re.split()` returns empty strings at the start and end of the string from the delimiters at the start and end of the string (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924509/why-are-there-extra-empty-strings-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-list-returned)).  To remove them, they can be filtered out, or otherwise look-behind or look-ahead conditions can be used which add to the pattern's complexity, as earlier answers to this question demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer seems to not be the easiest among them all but i hope it helps you.

```
data: str = "b123+xyz=1+z1$"

symbols: str = "+=$"

merge_text: str = ""
for char in data:
    if char not in symbols:
        merge_text += char
    else:
        # insert a unique character for splitting
        merge_text += ","
        merge_text += char
        merge_text += ","

final_result: list = merge_text.split(",")
```