# Pandas - Applying operation to dataframe but skipping over NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this Series data that can look like this

```
1         532
2         554
3         NaN
...       ... 
Name: score, Length: 941940, dtype: str
```

and I split it into 3 columns on each character using `apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)`, but it throws an error for the index 3 because it's `NaN`. How do I use `apply` so that it supports NaN and splits the value like below?

```
        score_0  score_1  score_2
1       5          3        2
2       5          5        4     
3       NaN        NaN      NaN          
...     ...        ...      ...
[941940 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: In the future, include a minimum working example of your code. For example, there is no context for your lambda function, and it doesn't appear to do anything

Comment: What is mysterious, @user19077881, is the fact that the OP's  series has `dtype: str`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution (similar to @GodIsOne's), which uses `regex` to avoid splitting at the beginning and the end of each number:

```
s.str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\d)', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0    5    3    2
1    5    5    4
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str.split("", expand=True)` to split each character into separate columns.  And this passes over `NaN` values:

```py
# split each character, delete first and last columns of empties.
df = ser.str.split("", expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1]
# rename columns
df.columns = [f"score_{i}" for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

An explanation for why there are additional columns created can be found in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924509/why-are-there-extra-empty-strings-at-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-list-returned).

Answer (score 0):

I will take a minimum example:

```
import numpy as np
s=pd.Series(['532','554',np.nan])

print(s)

0    532
1    554
2    NaN
dtype: object

k=s.str.split("",expand=True).fillna(np.nan)
```

To omit first and last column:

```
k=k.iloc[:, 1:-1]
print(k)
    1   2   3
0   5   3   2
1   5   5   4
2   NaN NaN NaN
```

---

```
k.columns = ["score_{}".format(i) for i in range(len(k.columns))]

print(k)

    score_0 score_1 score_2
0   5   3   2
1   5   5   4
2   NaN NaN NaN
```