# Split by regex without resulting empty strings in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string containing irregularly repeating delimiter, like method `split()` does:

```
>>> ' a b   c  de  '.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```

However, when I apply split by regular expression, the result is different (empty strings sneak into the resulting list):

```
>>> re.split('\s+', ' a b   c  de  ')
['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'de', '']
>>> re.split('\.+', '.a.b...c..de..')
['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'de', '']
```

And what I want to see:

```
>>>some_smart_split_method('.a.b...c..de..')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```

Comment: have also a look at [Why are empty strings returned in split() results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The empty strings are just an inevitable result of the regex split ([though there is good reasoning as to why that behavior might be desireable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results)). To get rid of them you can call filter on the result.

```
results = re.split(...)
results = list(filter(None, results))
```

Note the list() transform is only necessary in Python 3 -- in Python 2 filter() returns a list, while in 3 it returns a filter object.

Comment: Is there a way then to get split with limited number of splits?
`>>>split('.a.b...c', 1)

['a', 'b...c']

>>>split('a.b...c', 1)
['a', 'b...c']`

Comment: Yes, actually, pretty much exactly as you wrote it. For example, split(regex, string, 1) will stop splitting after the first match. You can see more in the python regex docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', ' a b   c  de  ')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```

Comment: That's awesome solution, a lot of posts are suggesting to use groups instead, but findall does everything.