# Regular expression split unexpected empty string item

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this example

```py
"BODY: 88% RECYCLED POLYESTER, 12% ELASTANE GUSSET LINING: 91% COTTON, 9% ELASTANE EXCLUSIVE OF DECORATION"
```

And I want to split them so that a word with a colon starts a new list item, while keeping that colon word

```py
["BODY: 77% RECYCLED POLYESTER, 23% ELASTANE", "MESH: 84% POLYAMIDE, 16% ELASTANE EXCLUSIVE OF DECORATION"]
```

I came up with

```py
re.split("\s(\w+:.+)", p)
```

But this returns an empty string at the end and I'm not sure why

```py
['BODY: 77% RECYCLED POLYESTER, 23% ELASTANE', 'MESH: 84% POLYAMIDE, 16% ELASTANE EXCLUSIVE OF DECORATION', '']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split by regex without resulting empty strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933216/split-by-regex-without-resulting-empty-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.split(r"\s(?=\w+:)", s)`. I added a lookahead `?=` to ensure the split occurs only on the space character that has the `\w+:` pattern following it.

The original attempt includes the entire pattern in the split group leading to undesirable results (if you include multiple `word:` groups, you'll see there are bigger problems than just the trailing empty string).

Here's a comparison:

```
>>> s = "foo: bar bar baz: asdfa sdfasd quux: zzzz"
>>> #                ^                 ^
>>> # we want to split on the highlighted space characters above
>>>
>>> re.split(r"\s(\w+:.+)", s) # incorrect
['foo: bar bar', 'baz: asdfa sdfasd quux: zzzz', '']
>>> re.split(r"\s(?=\w+:)", s) # correct
['foo: bar bar', 'baz: asdfa sdfasd', 'quux: zzzz']
```

If you want to handle splitting on multiple spaces, you can use `r"\s+(?=\w+:)"`.

Note also raw strings should be used for all regex literals to ensure nothing is inadvertently escaped.