# How to split at spaces and commas in Python?

Tags: python, regex, split

I've been looking around here, but I didn't find anything that was close to my problem. I'm using Python3.
I want to split a string at every whitespace and at commas. Here is what I got now, but I am getting some weird output:
(Don't worry, the sentence is translated from German)

```
    import re
    sentence = "We eat, Granny" 
    split = re.split(r'(\s|\,)', sentence.strip())
    print (split)

    >>>['We', ' ', 'eat', ',', '', ' ', 'Granny']
```

What I actually want to have is:

```
    >>>['We', ' ', 'eat', ',', ' ', 'Granny']
```

Comment: The comma looks very important here :), but you do not need to escape it

Comment: See [Why are empty strings returned in split() results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2197451/2564301) for some more on those empty strings.

Comment: indeed the comma is important (in german) otherwise you eat granny :), Thanks Rad Lexus,i will have look

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for findall instead of split and just match all the desired contents, like

```
import re
sentence = "We eat, Granny" 
print(re.findall(r'\s|,|[^,\s]+', sentence))
```

Comment: yes that perfectly works! eventhough i dont understand whats the difference in my  attempt! Thanks!

Comment: The main difference is the use of `findall` instead of `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way:

```
import re
sentence = "We eat, Granny"
split = [a for a in re.split(r'(\s|\,)', sentence.strip()) if a]
```

Output:

```
['We', ' ', 'eat', ',', ' ', 'Granny']
```

Works with both python 2.7 and 3[image]

Comment: your proposal yields: ['We', 'eat', '', 'Granny']

Comment: It returns the same output as what you asked for, for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 import re
 sentence = "We eat, Granny" 
 split = list(filter(None, re.split(r'(\s|\,)', sentence.strip())))
 print (split)
```

Comment: it somehow yields: 
<filter object at 0x000000000514A208>