# Why is the split() returning list objects that are empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I just got introduced to the `re` module and I learnt that it could be used to split strings very well. Then I wrote the following code:

```
import re
print(re.split(r'[a-f]','abcdefghtuyi op re the'))
```

I expected that Python would return:

```
['ghtuyi op r', ' th',] # as all the alphabets from a to f are expected to be sliced
```

But it returned:

```
['' '', '', '', '', '', 'ghtuyi op r', ' th', '']
```

Why are these blank list objects appearing?

Also, I did take a look at this question: [Why are empty strings returned in split() results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results) but it has nothing to do with `re`. How do I get rid of these blank objects while using the `re` module?

Comment: Consider this: `*a*b*c*d*e*f*ghtuyi op r*e* th*e*` – I put a star in every place that the original string will be split at by splitting it on any letter `a-f`. The split letters themselves are not included, so you get a lot of blank results there.

Comment: This was answered already in the other question but in general if you want to get rid of empty strings in a list you could easily do:

    new_list = []
    for element in old_list:
        if element != "":
            new_list.append(element)

#(with the right indentation)