# Python string.split() How to ignore empty spaces

Tags: python, string, split

I'm using `split` to parse http requests and came across something that I do not like but don't know a better way.

Imagine I have this GET : `/url/hi`

I'm splitting the url simply like so:

```
fields = request['url'].split('/')
```

It's simple, it works but it also makes the contents of the list have the first position as an empty string. I know this is expected behavior.

The question is: Can I change the calling of split to contemplate such thing or do I just live with it?

Comment: If you always want to ignore the first match you could write something like:
`fields = request['url'].split('/')[1:]`

Comment: this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844548/9050514

Answer (score 1):

If you just always want to remove the first entry to the list you could just do this:

```
fields = request['url'].split('/')[1:]
```

If you just want to remove any empty strings from the list you can use instead follow your initial call with this:

```
fields.remove('')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: what if the string has more than one empty string

Comment: In that case I would use a the built in filter function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If you sure your string start with '/'
you can ignore first character like this:

```
url = request['url']
fields = url[1:].split('/')   #[1: to end]
```

If your not sure, simple check first:

```
url = request['url']
if url.startswith('/'):
    url = url[1:]
fields = url.split('/')
```

Happy coding