# Why is there an empty string, and only one, created when I split a string by "?"

Tags: python, string, split

I'm working with this code to learn about passing parameters into `split()`.
If I pass `"?"` into the call to `split()` on the string `y`, it's splitting them into a list as you would expect, but it's adding an additional empty string right at the end. This applies whether there is one or more `'?'` in the string (3 in the example string below.

Can anyone tell me why it's doing this?

It doesn't seem to do this if I pass in a character like `'s'`.

```
    y = "Is this a sentence? And is this one? Hm?"
    z = y.split("?")
    print(len(z))
    print(z)
    for w in z:
        print(w)
```

This is the output:

```
4
['This is a sentence', ' And is this one', ' Hm', '']
This is a sentence
 And is this one
 Hm
```

Comment: Because after the last `'?'` comes an empty string.

Comment: So is there a secret empty string at the end of this/any string?

Comment: [Why are empty strings returned in split() results?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2197451)

Comment: Not secret. `split` gives you what is before and after the `'?'`. There's no characters after the last `'?'`, so it has to give you an empty string.

Comment: wow, thank you for such a clear explanation.

Comment: @timgeb your answer is better than any on the linked question/answers. Would be great if you could add it there.

Comment: @Jules_ewls https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317388/3620003 I posted in the other topic because this one is closed...