# How do I stop regex from matching unwanted empty strings?

Tags: python, regex

Im working on a problem set to count sentences. I decided to implement by using regular expressions to split the string at the characters "?, ., !". When I pass my text to re.split, it is including an empty string at the end of the list.

source code:

```
from cs50 import get_string
import re


def main():
    text = get_string("Text: ")
    cole_liau(text)


# Implement 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8; l = avg num of letters / 100 words , S = avg num of sentences / 100 words
def cole_liau(intext):

    words = []
    letters = []

    sentences = re.split(r"[.!?]+", intext)
    print(sentences)
    print(len(sentences))

main()
```

Output:

Text: Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places! You're off and away!

```
['Congratulations', ' Today is your day', " You're off to Great Places", " You're off and away", '']
```

5

I tried adding the + expression to make sure it was matching at least 1 [.!?] but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.split` is working fine here. You have a `!` at the end of the last sentence, so it will split the text before (a sentence), and after (a null character).

You can just add `[:-1]` at the end of your line to remove the last element of the list :

```
sentences = re.split(r"[.!?]+", intext)[:-1]
```

Output :

```
['Congratulations', ' Today is your day', " You're off to Great Places", " You're off and away"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a comprehension:

```
def cole_liau(intext):

    words = []
    letters = []

    sentences = [sent for sent in re.split(r"[.!?]+", intext) if sent]
    print(sentences)
    print(len(sentences))
```

Which yields

```
['Congratulations', ' Today is your day', " You're off to Great Places", " You're off and away"]
4
```

As to why `re.split()` returns an empty string, see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197451/why-are-empty-strings-returned-in-split-results).

Comment: Using a comprehension here is expensive, it iterates through all the list just to remove the last element.

Comment: @totok: Not really, it could be the first element, the last or anything in between.